# Compute $\oint \frac{dz}{e^z(z^2-1)^2}$ on $|z|=2$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Compute the integral $\oint \frac{dz}{e^z(z^2-1)^2}$ on $|z|=2$.

Background: Wunsch Complex Analysis chapter 4.5 #23

Does someone see my mistake? Textbook answer: $-\pi i e^{-1}$

Using $2\pi i (f_{z1}'(i)+f_{z2}'(-i))$
My attempt:
$$2\pi i \left(-\left[\frac{e^z(z+i)^2+e^z(2)(z+i)}{(e^z(z+i)^2)^2}\right]_i+-\left[\frac{e^z(z-i)^2+e^z(2)(z-i)}{(e^z(z-i)^2)^2}\right]_{-i}\right)$$
$$2\pi i\left(\frac{1-i}{e^i4}+\frac{e^i(1+i)}{4}\right)$$
$$\pi(i\cos1-i\sin(1))$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$z=1$ and $z=-1$ are poles with degree 2. I don't know why but it seems that you are calculating Residues at $z= i$ and $z= -i$ but your function is analythic at these points. 
$$
Res(f;z=1) = \lim\limits_{z\to 1}\frac{d}{dz}(\frac{1}{e^z(z+1)^2})=-\frac{1}{2e}
$$
$$
Res(f;z=-1) = \lim\limits_{z\to -1}\frac{d}{dz}(\frac{1}{e^z(z-1)^2})=0.
$$
Then, by Residue theorem you obtain the answer in the textbook.

Comment: See edit, I forgot square in denominator of question.

Comment: Well. It is very similar, but with the formula for higher order poles:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Limit_formula_for_higher_order_poles

Comment: Yes, but his answer uses $\pm 1$ not $\pm i$ but the error I made was somewhere in simplifying the first derivative in the 2 residues. Did I write enough out or should I add more of my steps?

Comment: If $i$ is a pole, then the denominator is wrong m. Should be $z^2+1$ instead of minus)

Comment: That was my mistake.